# Change the Show Hidden Items setting on a folder

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8.1

Where is the setting to "show / hide items" on a particular folder stored?

I looking to be able to change it programmatically, hopefully in Powershell.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, you want to change the file system attributs ?

Comment: If that's where that setting is stored for a certain folder, then "yes".

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken about being able to set this at a folder-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So try this :

```
$file = "c:\temp\t.txt"
# Hidde  $file
Set-ItemProperty -Path $file -Name attributes  -Value ([io.fileattributes]::Hidden)
# Remove Hidden if set 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $file -Name attributes  -Value ((Get-ItemProperty $file).attributes -bxor ([io.fileattributes]::Hidden))
```

Answer (score 0):

I try you're code but this part doesn't work:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $file -Name attributes  -Value ((Get-ItemProperty $file).attributes -bxor ([io.fileattributes]::Hidden))
```

I just replace "hiden" by "normal" and it's work:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $file -Name attributes  -Value ([io.fileattributes]::Normal)
```

Thank you.